# Сравнить пароль пользователя БД PostgreSQL и введенный пароль Qt 4

Tags: qt, postgresql, qt4

Как узнать, совпадает ли пароль, введенный в форме, с паролем для пользователя СУБД PostgreSQL, средствами Qt 4? 
Предположим, у пользователя пароль 12345.

```
select md5('12345')
```

и

```
QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(("12345"),QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex())
```

дают  результат "827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b".
В таблице для этого же пароля хранится "md5b5ab06cb9f5f50555a65efe870fbf406"

Как, зная пароль, введенный в форму и значение поля passwd из таблицы pg_shadow, сравнить их?

Comment: Не зная метода хэширования (соль, многократное хэширование и т.д.), никак. Исходники надо смотреть.

Comment: b5ab06cb9f5f50555a65efe870fbf406 - 12345jjj, так что хэширование там явно MD5, о чем и префикс намекает. Но откуда эти jjjj - не понятно...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов jjjj это получается логин пользователя) нашел в тырнете вот такую штуку: `select * from pg_shadow where ('md5' || md5('12345'||pg_shadow.usename)) = pg_shadow.passwd`. Т.е. в конце еще приписывается логин. Т.е., получается, нужно сверять то значение, которое получено из таблицы, с `QString("md5" + QCryptographicHash::hash(("12345" +"jjjj"),QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex())`, если логин jjjj :) Верно?

Comment: Проверьте :-) У меня уже башка не варит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опытным путем и по комментариям ТСа выяснено, что `md5b5ab06cb9f5f50555a65efe870fbf406` содержит префикс `md5`, а оставшаяся часть - MD5 хэш строки `12345jjj`, в которой `12345` - пароль, я `jjj` - логин.